# java exception handling nested methods

Tags: java, exception

Is it good design to catch exceptions in a method where enclosed methods already catch the exception? For example, in the following code a public method calls 2 private methods. The private methods already catch any exception and print it:

```
/*The only thing this method does is call the enclosed methods.*/
public Object enclosingmethod()
{
    try
    {
       enclosedmethod1();
       enclosedmethod2();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printstacktrace();
    }
}


private Object enclosedmethod1()
{
    try
     {
       //some logic
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       e.printstacktrace();
     }
}

private Object enclosedmethod2()
{
    try
     {
       //some logic
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       e.printstacktrace();
     }
}
```

Comment: Probably not really worth doing unless the enclosed method rethrow the exception or throw a different one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not good design. And especially in this case it is wrong, because you surround the calls of `enclosedmethod1` and `enclosedmethod2` in a catch block, but **don't even throw an exception** in these blocks, because all Exceptions are caught!

Especially not to catch the mother of all exceptions, `java.lang.Exception`.

But as always it depends. Ask yourself the question: what is supposed to happen when `enclosedmethod1` encounters an exception? Should the code continue to be executed? because if you catch it, `enclosedmethod2` will still be executed. Should it? I can't tell you, but maybe you can, because you know what `enclosedmethod1` and `enclosedmethod2` are supposed to do.

*There is no general answer to this question*, because it depends on your requirements.

But as always, *take your time to think about exception handling*.

Answer (score 0):

It won't do anything for you to catch it in the parent method, unless the enclosed methods are re-throwing the exception.

If you use a good IDE, they will tell you when you are unnecessarily catching exceptions (and alternatively, when a method needs to catch a particular exception).

Also, as others have said, you don't typically want to be catching 'Exception' explicitly; you'll want to be catching the exceptions that could actually be thrown by the code in the try block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will sometimes nest method calls that catch exceptions and then also catch exceptions in higher level methods that call the nested methods, however **not as you are doing it** since you rarely want to catch exceptions so generally, and you wouldn't want to catch the same exception that has already been handled in the nested method call unless it is re-thrown. Instead much better is to catch *specific* exceptions where they are needed to be handled, and not to randomly or generally try to catch all exceptions everywhere. Sometimes inner methods will catch a specific exception and then throw one of their own exceptions which will then need to be handled by higher level methods.